# using xargs to get and parse a filename within multiple greps

Tags: parsing, grep, xargs

I am trying to use multiple greps to get 2 lines related to a specific ID which is contained in a set of files. I would like to use xargs and some form of parsing (sed perhaps) to get the appropriate filename from a different set of files.
the command to get the filename is

```
grep "ID_A" fileset1.txt | head
```

and that gives the output:

```
idSet.filename2.IDs: ID_A
```

then the second command to get the desired data is:

```
zgrep -C 30 "ID_A" filename2.txt.gz | grep -C 2 -F ":port"
```

so the first command is just to get the name "filename2", and I am trying to combine these to get the results in one big command.

I know i can use xargs to run the first command within the second, but i'm not sure of the syntax or how to parse it to get just the filename2.

any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: so the output of the first command is one or few lines? considering it is just one, say `idSet.XXX.IDs`, then you need to `zgrep ... XXX.txt.gz`, right?

Comment: the result of the first grep is one line and the " | head" makes sure of that. after that, yes, I need the zgrep to run on the XXX.txt.gz as you said

Comment: if it helps, the XXX is a consistent pattern, specifically :

logfile-YYYY.MM.DD.HH

for example:

logfile-2015.01.05.09